# Number/alpha icons... Where to download?

Tags: html, css, image, icons

I wonder where I can download free icon packs for development?  I already have the major icon packs like the silk icons from [famfamfam](http://www.famfamfam.com/) but I can't find other good quality icons to use in my projects. So if you know nice free icons (especially number and alpha icons) it would be nice to post a link here.

Comment: Not a real SO question in my opinion. We are using Icon Experience, commercial and worth every dollar.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images

On 2nd page of the most popular questions if all time on SO

Answer (score 1):

this isn't really a programming question; but I'd have a look at [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/); they often have high quality free icon packs posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favourite icon Archive: [IconArchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to visit [iconpacks.net](https://www.iconpacks.net/)